# More concise way to append a value to a dict array-element?

Tags: python

When I want to append a newvalue into Dict under Key, I find myself have to write:

```
# Dict={}
# Key = ....
# newvalue = ....

if not Key in Dict:
    Dict[Key] = [ newvalue ]
else:
    Dict[Key].append(newvalue)
```

It costs four lines of code. Is there a more concise way with python standard library? e.g

```
Dict.appendkeyvalue(Key, newvalue)
```

Comment: Hint: By convention, uppercase variable names should only be used for classes (but don't use built-in names like `dict` either).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

d['something'].append(3)
print d['something']
# > [3]
```

Comment: If you don't want to be every Key a list, write a short function containing your four-liner.

Answer (score 3):

With standard dictionaries, you can use [`setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
d = {}
d.setdefault("something", []).append(3)
```

`setdefault()` here returns `d["something"]` if it exists, otherwise it creates a new dictionary entry with `[]` as its value and returns that.

Comment: @Autopulated -- In this case, you frequently create a new list just to discard it immediately.

Comment: @mgilson: What do you mean? No list gets discarded here.

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- Only because `d` doesn't have a `"something"` key.  If it did have a `"something"` key, then the list which is passed to `setdefault` as the second argument would be discarded.

Comment: I see, good point. I wonder whether that significantly affects performance.